# Не сохраняются header и footer при переносе сайта на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, перенос

Wordpress 5.7.6, Astra 3.8.0, PHP 7.4

Переношу сайт с виртуального хостинга на локальный сервер с заменой доменного имени.
Файлы FTP скопировал, wp-config.php настроил, базу отредактировал с автозаменой старого доменного имени на новое.
Сайт заработал, но со странностями:
Исчезла фоновая картинка, а также хедер и футер, вместо меню «шапка» и «футер» на редактировании страницы Astra выводит меню «конструктор хедера» и «конструктор футера», предлагая создать их заново.
Сайт на удаленном хостинге — https://prnt.sc/k_hg2_tBY23E
Его локальная копия — https://prnt.sc/3IvMq7Z2NJ_v

Что я только уже не делал — и скачивал сайт разными FTP-клиентами с мыслью что могло что-то скачаться неправильно, и в базе ковырялся, как мог — все осталось таким же.
Если кто поможет, буду рад.

Comment: разлогиньтесь на сайте

Comment: Разлогиниться, а затем скачать еще раз файлы и базу, или только базу?

Comment: пробуйте и кэш чистите

Comment: кэш в базе, браузере или на FTP? на FTP папки "cache" пусты.
Если Вы имеете в виду кэш браузера, то я заходил после этого в режими инкогнито в разных браузерах, результат один

Comment: В браузере попробуйте почистить

Comment: Чистил, в разных браузерах открывал. После этого перекачивать сайт заново, или нет смысла?

Comment: Читай и переноси правильно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress

Comment: Воспользуйтесь мануалом ссылку на который Вам дали выше. Если коротко, то вот эти данные из конструктора хедера и футера хранятся в базе данных как сериализованные данные, которые "сыпятся" при переносе "ручками".

Comment: SeVlad, дубликатором не получится, т.к. будет меняться доменное имя. По вашей же ссылке написано, что в базе все пути - абсолютные. Тут только автозамена в базе. Пути /var/www/test/ менял на нужные. Я несколько раз переносил сайты на вордпрессе, просто скачивая ftp-клиентом файлы и делая в базе автозамену доменного имени, ну и wp-config конечно. Все работало. Почему-то сейчас не работает.

Comment: Simon, я прочел мануал. Но у меня будет меняться доменное имя, как поступить в этом случае?

Comment: Ещё раз: читай ман. Дупликатором всё получится. Для этого он и создан.

Comment: Странно что создатели Wordpress сделали такую гадость... Попробую дубликатор. А если бы не было изменения имени домена, можно было бы просто базу скопировать?

Comment: В очаредной раз удивляюсь и разочаровываюсь в вордпрессе, даже банальный перенос скриптов и базы оборачивается такием геморроем

Comment: @tim68 если бы не было смены домена, то можно было бы просто скопировать.

Comment: Simon, там еще были переменные вида /var/www/test/ в базе, но судя по всему это был кэш, который ни на что не влиял.

Comment: SeVlad, Simon - большое спасибо вам, сделал через дупликатор. Однако такая зависимость от плагинов пугает...

Comment: @tim68 а чем пугает?) Работая с PHP фреймворками, например, Вы будете зависимы от composer пакетов, а разрабатывая фронтенд или бек на JS, будете зависимы от npm пакетов, которые по своей сути тоже являются плагинами, в какой-то мере)

Comment: Simon например тем, что завтра разработчик может забросить плагин, или заблокировать российские сервера в виде санкций, а руками не перенести. Я лично считаю эти сериализированные данные ненужным усложнением, которое только мешает

Comment: @Simon >"если бы не было смены домена, то можно было бы просто скопировать". Нет. Засада не столько в домене (он редко где в сериалы попадает), сколько в путях.

Comment: @tim68. Ты не там проблему с ВП видишь :) Но тут комменты не предназначены для обсуждений. Как и вообще SO. Это не форум.